# Как освободить память выделенную для массивов или переменных?

Tags: java

Можно ли освободить память после использования массива или переменной, если этот массив или переменная больше не понадобится?

Comment: про garbage collector читали? деструктора в джаве нет, но вы можете вызвать System.gc(), вместе с тем надо понимать, что нет гарантий немедленного исполнения)

Comment: Нужно чтобы у переменных не было ссылок на объект, например через обнуление переменной, т.е. `= null`, после этим объектом когда-нибудь займется сборщик мусора, но можно его вызвать вручную, но гарантий немедленного выполнения нет: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc()

Comment: @Дмитрий, а если память выделяется в методе, то после вызова этого метода GC не освободит память?

Comment: @CeramicThree, смотрите, вы создаете объект и кладете его в переменную, на объект теперь ссылаются, сборщик мусора не сможет его удалить, но если вы в ту переменную поместите другой объект или обнулите ее, то у объекта счетчик ссылок уменьшится и если ссылок будет 0, то это показание на удаление. Если же вы из метода вернете тот объект, и в какую-то переменную положите, то у объекта счетчик ссылок увеличится на 1, но если в методе тот объект хранился в переменной, то при выходе из области видимости (из метода), то счетчик ссылок уменьшится

Comment: после вызова освободит, но это не значит, что это произойдет сразу после. мало того, все зависит от того, на какие объекты у вас есть ссылки в рантайме. предположим, у вас есть метод. в нем создается 3 коллекции и 10 перменных, но метод возвращает 1 стринг. видимость переменных ограничена методом, после его исполнения у вас есть только одна сслыка на объект - возвращаемый стринг. посему все остальное без особого труда будет автоматически удалено из памяти

Comment: @gil9red не совсем так, при сборке мусора GC смотрит не на количество ссылок, которые указывают на объект, а на его достижимость. То есть даже если у вас есть объекты, которые циклически ссылаются друг на друга (например `A -> B -> C -> A`) но при этом не достижимы из кода, то GC их удалит, даже при том факте, что на них кто-то ссылается.

Comment: @CeramicThree GC все сделает за вас, не пытайтесь делать его работу, вы ему так только помешаете